# How to make a save/load function for a board of an array? in C

Tags: c, file

Basically I took on this project of making a Connect Four game in C , I managed to make it work but decided to go one step further trying to make a save game / load game function for the game. I really don't know what should I even google to find the answer for this one. I need to be able to save the state of the board:
[image]

Specifically i need to save the state of the board in a .txt file.
Or at least try.
And to be able to exit the programm, and re-enter then load the game by scaning an ID given when saved.

So I have two questions :

1. How should i go about saving such a structure in a file.txt
2. How to make it so that by entering an id it corresponds to a specifical board or simplier ... imagine a list of lines in a .txt which goes

ID NAME

ID NAME

and by scanning the id you get the corresponding name

this is the code: (have fun)

````````````````````````````````````````````````
    //libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//define
#define BOARD_ROWS 6
#define BOARD_COLS 7

//functions
int mainMenu();
void printBoard(char *board);
int game();
int takeTurn(char *board, int player, const char *PIECES);
int checkWin(char *board);
int checkFour(char *board, int, int, int, int);
int horizontalCheck(char *board);
int verticalCheck(char *board);
int diagonalCheck(char *board);

//function for game and some game logic
int game(){
    const char *PIECES = "XO";
    char board[BOARD_COLS * BOARD_ROWS];
    memset(board, ' ', BOARD_COLS * BOARD_ROWS);

    int turn, done = 0;

    for(turn = 0; turn < BOARD_COLS * BOARD_ROWS && !done; turn++){
        printBoard(board);
        while(!takeTurn(board, turn % 2, PIECES)){
            printBoard(board);
            printf("COLUMN FULL!\n");
        }
        done=checkWin(board);
    }
    printBoard(board);

    if(turn == BOARD_COLS * BOARD_ROWS && !done){
        printf("It's a tie!");
    } else{
        turn--;
        printf("Player %d (%c) wins!\n", turn % 2 + 1, PIECES[turn % 2]);
    }
    return 0;
}

//function that prints the board
void printBoard(char *board){
    int row, col;

    printf("\nConnect-4\n");
    printf("-----------------------------\n");
    for(row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS; row++){
      for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS; col++){
         printf("| %c ",  board[BOARD_COLS * row + col]);
      }
      puts("|");
      puts("-----------------------------");

   }
   puts("  1   2   3   4   5   6   7\n");
}

//check win
int checkWin(char *board){
    return (horizontalCheck(board) || verticalCheck(board) || diagonalCheck(board));
}

int checkFour(char *board, int a, int b, int c, int d){
    //board[a] = won;
    //board[b] = won;
    //board[c] = won;
    //board[d] = won;
    return (board[a] == board[b] && board[b] == board[c] && board[c] == board[d] && board[a] != ' ');
}

int horizontalCheck(char *board){
    int row, col, idx;
    const int WIDTH = 1;

    for(row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS; row++){
       for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS - 3; col++){
          idx = BOARD_COLS * row + col;
          if(checkFour(board, idx, idx + WIDTH, idx + WIDTH * 2, idx + WIDTH * 3)){
             return 1;
          }
       }
    }
    return 0;
}

int verticalCheck(char *board){
    int row, col, idx;
    const int HEIGHT = 7;

    for(row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS - 3; row++){
       for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS; col++){
          idx = BOARD_COLS * row + col;
          if(checkFour(board, idx, idx + HEIGHT, idx + HEIGHT * 2, idx + HEIGHT * 3)){
              return 1;
          }
       }
    }
    return 0;
}

//diagonal check for win
int diagonalCheck(char *board){
   int row, col, idx, count = 0;
   const int DIAG_RGT = 6, DIAG_LFT = 8;

   for(row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS - 3; row++){
      for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS; col++){
         idx = BOARD_COLS * row + col;
         if(((count <= 3) && (checkFour(board, idx, idx + DIAG_LFT, idx + DIAG_LFT * 2, idx + DIAG_LFT * 3))) ||
             ((count >= 3) && (checkFour(board, idx, idx + DIAG_RGT, idx + DIAG_RGT * 2, idx + DIAG_RGT * 3)))){
            return 1;
         }
         count++;
      }
      count = 0;
   }
   return 0;
}

//function to take turns between players
int takeTurn(char *board, int player, const char *PIECES){
    int row, col = 0;
    printf("Player %d (%c):\nEnter number coordinate: ", player + 1, PIECES[player]);

    while(1){
        if(1 != scanf("%d", &col) || col < 1 || col > 7){
            if(col == 0){
                //saveGame();```````````````````````````````````````````````this````````````````````````````` 
            }
            else{
                while(getchar() != '\n');
                printf("Number out of bounds! Try again!");
            }
        }else {
            break;
        }
    }
    col--;

    for(row = BOARD_ROWS - 1; row >= 0; row--){
      if(board[BOARD_COLS * row + col] == ' '){
         board[BOARD_COLS * row + col] = PIECES[player];
         return 1;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}

//===================================================================================================================================================
//function that displays the main menu
int mainMenu(){
    int selection, selectionWrong;
    do{
        printf("Connect-4 Game\n");
        printf("_______________\n");
        printf("1.Play a new game\n");
        printf("2.Load already existing game\n");//print the main menu look
        printf("Exit the game\n");
        printf("Choose option(1-3):\n");

        selectionWrong = 0;//set to 0 and if scan is correct(1,2,3) we get out of loop because it does not get in if loop

        scanf("%d",&selection);
        if (selection > 3 || selection < 1){//if it is wrong
            selectionWrong = 1;//we set to 1 so that it loops since while will only break when it is 0 (does not get in if loop)
            printf("Selection is out of bounds! Try again!\n");
        }
    }
    while(selectionWrong);//while it get's in if loop it puts error and asks to try again

    if(selection == 1) game();

    if(selection == 2)

    if(selection == 3) return 0;//EXIT GAME OPTION

    return 0;
}

//main function
int main()
{
    mainMenu();//display main menu and take choice
}
````````````````````````````````````````````````

i know this is to much maybe.. but when i asked last time i got so many comments about a not specific enought question ...well now it better not be too specific :)

Comment: 1. Define file format to express what should be saved. 2. Write code to load & save the file format. 3 Debug your code if it doesn't work well.

Comment: @mikeCAT well yeah thats what I'm asking how to do

Comment: Surely it can't be that hard to define a file format. If you had to describe the board state on paper with just normal text characters what would you write? Heck, you can even dump exactly what you have shown on the console into a file. Though of course there are more compact ways of representing the data but you have to start somewhere.

Comment: @kaylum i know how to write it in a file however if i load it afterwards how can i make it work , i dont't really understand how is this possible

Comment: You just do the reverse of the writing process. So for example, the file format may be one single line with each character representing one element in the `board` array. Then to load it just read each character and copy it back into a new `board` array. Then you might have another line which states which players turn it is which can be used to intialise the `turn` variable. And so on.

Comment: @kaylum that makes sense thank you! I'll try it.